# Using MongoDB in terminal which is running by AMPPS in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, mongodb, terminal, ubuntu-14.04, ampps

I have AMPPS up and running in my ubuntu which is in `/usr/local/ampps/` directory.

I want to use MongoDB which is available in AMPPS - I have started the MongoDB server from AMPPS control panel.

but I'm not able to use it from terminal,I'm in `/usr/local/ampps/mongodb/bin/` directory and when I'm using `./mongo db mydb` I get :

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.0
connecting to: use
2016-10-04T09:29:04.921+0330 E -        [main] file [mydb] doesn't exist
failed to load: mydb
```

How can I use mongoDB from terminal ?

FYI : I used mysql which it was running by AMPPS in terminal this way :

```
cd /usr/local/ampps/mysql/bin/
./mysql -u root -p
```

And I was able to use mysql from terminal.

Comment: Same thing here, how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Figured how to do this, just cd in the AMPPS folder :

```
cd /usr/local/ampps/mongodb/bin
```

Then run :

```
./mongo
```

you will get something like this :

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.0
connecting to: test
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
    http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
Server has startup warnings: 
2016-10-04T09:08:12.567+0330 I CONTROL  [main] ** WARNING: --rest is specified without --httpinterface,
2016-10-04T09:08:12.567+0330 I CONTROL  [main] **          enabling http interface
2016-10-04T09:08:38.127+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2016-10-04T09:08:38.127+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-10-04T09:08:38.127+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-10-04T09:08:38.127+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-10-04T09:08:38.127+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-10-04T09:08:38.127+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-10-04T09:08:38.127+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-10-04T09:08:38.127+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-10-04T09:08:38.127+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
>
```

And as you can see you can type your commands in front of `>` like :

```
> show dbs
admin  0.078GB
local  0.078GB
mydb   0.078GB
>
```